# Why is the ball on the left black in shading

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new to Blender.
I found in tutorials, their ball on the left is showing a landscape photo. But mine is plain black.
Can anyone tell me what it is and how to change it to a landscape photo?

[image: Other people's blender]
[image: My blender]

Comment: In the top of the 3D viewport, on the right, there are a bunch of icons that are menus.  Select the one at the far right that looks like a down arrow and add a screenshot of it, please.  It's where the settings that control that ball are.

Comment: Could be a bug. Which Blender version do you use? The bug is fixed in the current 2.93.5 version and doesn't occur in 2.92. But the early Blender 2.93.x versions have this bug related to Intel UHD graphics that results in a black material when the *roughness* value is very low. In this case, the left *HDRI Preview* sphere is black because it has a roughness of 0.